# I removed KDE plasma desktop and stuck in a command screen

Tags: kde, plasma

I am new to Linux. I have just installed Ubuntu and after removing the KDE plasma desktop and reboot the system. I am stuck in a black command screen. Not sure how to get to the default Ubuntu desktop screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have installed  ubuntu-desktop befor remove kde plasma apply this command after login by user name (write your user name and press enter) and password in the black screen:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

choose OK and in second screen choose gdm3 and press enter if you have another desktop environment you will choose the appropriate display manager and press enter

if you don't have ubuntu-desktop  and want to install it apply :

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent 2 hours on this

Comment: don't worry I faced this problem before and spent  some time to install ubuntu desktop because I didn't know the problem in  display manager configuration.

Comment: I am getting unexpected errors from time to time. I feel something is trying to lunch but doesn't work. ( Didn't have this problem before I removed the KDE) I will try to get you the error code when I get it next time.

Comment: check your autosrart `/etc/xdg/autostart` my be some kde apps .desktop files not removed from autostart